# API de Notificação pagseguro não é executado

Tags: php

Estou utilizando o Pagseguro para gerenciar os pagamentos, utilizo o método `lightbox`, onde consigo efetuar tudo, inclusive o pagamento (tudo isso em sandbox).

Porém na hora de receber as notificações, o arquivo não está sendo chamado. Mesmo tendo configurado a url dentro do PagSeguro.

Veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu arquivo pag_retorno.php é este:

```
<?php
    $name = 'arquivo.txt';
    $text = "chegou".date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $file = fopen($name, 'a');
    fwrite($file, $text);
    fwrite($file, $status);
    fclose($file);

    if(isset($_POST['notificationType']) && $_POST['notificationType'] == 'transaction'){

        $name = 'arquivo.txt';
        $text = "chegou";
        $file = fopen($name, 'a');
        fwrite($file, $text);
        fwrite($file, $status);
        fclose($file);

        $email = 'meu@email.com'; //ja esta configurado
        $token = 'meutoken'; //ja esta configurado

        $url = 'https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions/notifications/' . $_POST['notificationCode'] . '?email=' . $email . '&token=' . $token;

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $transaction= curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        if($transaction == 'Unauthorized'){
            print_r("nao autorizado");
            exit;
        }
        $transaction = simplexml_load_string($transaction);

        $status = $transaction -> status;

        $name = 'arquivo.txt';
        $text = var_export($_POST, true);
        $file = fopen($name, 'a');
        fwrite($file, $text);
        fwrite($file, $status);
        fclose($file);

        print_r($status);
    }
?>
```

Como podem ver, coloquei até uma inscrição de data e aviso para saber se ao menos o arquivo foi chamado, coisa que não está acontecendo. Alguém saberia me orientar sobre como resolver isso?

---

#### Editado:

A mesma configuração de URL também foi feita dentro do ambiente SandBox.

Comment: Usando CloudFlare? Se sim, esse pode ser o problema. Outra coisa, se estiver em sandbox, lembre-se que as notificações são manuais.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Não não.

Comment: Em sandbox, você tem que ir em https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br e gerar as notificações manualmente. E funciona até mesmo em localhost.

Comment: Sim, eu estou fazendo isso. Mas por algum motivo não está dando. Estou tentando com a biblioteca deles e também com um php próprio (o citado no post). Em 4 tentativas, uma delas foi recebida, as outras deram uma falha de autenticação (até chegou ao arquivo) mas agora voltou a parar de receber. Estranho.

Comment: Duas coisas: usa *http* em vez de *https*. Outra coisa: se der erro "Unauthorized", significa que o e-mail ou o token está errado. O token de produção é diferente do token de sandbox.

Comment: Sim sim. A parte do unauthorized eu sei como proceder. O `https` não sei se vai ser possível remover no momento. Acho que o problema era a falta dessa linha: `header("access-control-allow-origin: https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br");` Pelo menos com a biblioteca deles funcionou. Vou tentar com o meu arquivo agora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muita dor de cabeça, o que resolveu meu problema foi este código:

```
header("access-control-allow-origin: https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br");
```

Adicionado logo na abertura da tag `PHP`.

Só fiquem atentos para a liberação de url de acordo com o ambiente. Sandbox ou produção.

Comment: Este seu codigo funciona ainda?